# Custom content per post in widget

Tags: plugins, widgets, plugin-recommendation

It's hard to explain, but I want to be able to do is fill in fields when creating a post, and these fields will populate a widget. So for each post the widget content is different and the widget content is inputted on the post - I don't want the plugins that show widgets only on certain posts - I have hundreds of posts and doing it that way would be a pain.

Does anyone know of a plugin that will achieve this? Free or paid I don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet there would be to [register a custom widget](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget) which accesses the global `$post` object and outputs the specific meta fields for that post.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I expected that to be the case - just thought I'd try and save some time and find a pre existing plugin.